# Erro quando o rato está em movimento

Tags: javascript

Estou a criar um sistema e preciso que se o rato estiver parado durante 3 segundos em cima de uma div faça algumas acções, eu tive a investigar e encontrei um código, ele está a funcionar normalmente mas ele fica a gerar erro no console sempre que o usuário mexe o rato, apesar de este erro não causar problemas ao funcionamento do site, alguém poderia-me ajudar a remover este erro?

PS: A função `setEvent()` é chamada também quando existe um hover sobre a div que falei acima

Erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: timeout is not defined

Código:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    if (timeout !== null) {
        $(".video_overlays").css("display", "block");    
        $(".trailer").css("cursor", "auto");    
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    setEvent();
});
function setEvent(){
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".video_overlays").fadeOut(2000);    
        $(".trailer").css("cursor", "none"); 
    }, 3000); 
}
```

Comment: Só para ter certeza: *rato* é o *mouse*, correto?

Comment: Sim rato é o mouse, eu sou pt por isso é que digo rato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, Tomás!

Imaginando o cenário do usuário entrando no site, ao mexer o mouse (ainda não chamou o hover `function setEvent` em uma div) ele vai tentar acessar a variável chamada `timeout` o qual possivelmente não existe (ainda) no escopo global, resultando no erro `is not defined`.

Logo após a chamada da `function setEvent`, a variável `timeout` torna-se conhecida no escopo global e já não será mostrado este erro quando o usuário movimentar o mouse no documento.

Para resolver este erro, basta defini-la no escopo global.

`var timeout = null` (fora das duas funções, podendo ser antes dessa primeira função)

Para entender mais sobre escopo:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es#Function_scope

Fica bem, abraços!

Comment: Obrigado era esse o problema!

Comment: Não precisa ser `var timeout = null`. Basta apenas declarar a variável, assim: `var timeout;`

Comment: Sim :), de nada!